# How to handle a window popup with wdio?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to handle a facebook auth dialog popup via webdriverio. The problem is that I can't seem to target the email/password fields for the facebook signup.

Here's my code:

```
it('redirects after signup', () => {
    browser.url('/');

    const mainTab = browser.getCurrentTabId();
    browser.waitForExist('[data-test="facebook-login-button"]');
    browser.click('[data-test="facebook-login-button"]');

    // fb login form
    browser.waitForExist('#email');
    browser.setValue('#email', this.fbAccount.email);
    browser.setValue('#pass', this.fbAccount.password);
    browser.click('input[type="submit"]');

    // fb login authorization
    browser.waitForExist('button[type="submit"]');
    browser.click('button[type="submit"]');

    browser.switchTab(mainTab);
    browser.waitForExist('[data-test="intro-title"]');
});
```

I had also attempted to wait until the tab opens by doing the following

```
browser.waitUntil(() => browser.getUrl().indexOf('facebook.com') > -1);
```

And another attempt was to switch tabs to the facebook tab more explicitly

```
browser.switchTab(   
 browser.windowHandles().value[browser.windowHandles().value.length]
);
```

All of these variants just result in `browser.waitForExist('#email');` failing (that is timing out and not finding the email input after 30s). That being said, the popup does indeed open, and it is indeed focused. Even when I manually try to focus wdio, webdriver or selenium doesn't find the element in question.

How is this sort of thing supposed to work? What am I doing wrong? Are there recommendations for making this sort of test successful?

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you actually need to find the right window handle. You can't guarantee the first or last one is the one you need. You can at least hope that the quantity of window handles is contained though.

I added the following code before the fb login form filling code:

```
// wait for popup
browser.waitUntil(() => browser.windowHandles().value.length > 1);
const popupWindow = browser.windowHandles().value.filter((handle) => handle !== mainTab)[0];
browser.switchTab(popupWindow);
```

This allowed me to guarantee that I handle the right windowHandle focused before moving on. I tried always selecting the first or last window handle, but that never worked out for me.

Note: in WDIO 5 you need to use `getWindowHandle`.